# Generating productions from lexer/parser grammar

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Is there a way to generate (all possible) sentences from a given grammar?

Let's say I have the grammar:

```
grammar Drink;

//Parser Rules
drinkSentence : ARTICLE? DRINKING_VESSEL OF drink ;
drink : TEXT;

// Lexer Rules
ARTICLE : 'the' | 'an' | 'a' ;
OF : 'of' ;
DRINKING_VESSEL : 'cup' | 'pint' | 'shot' | 'mug' | 'glass' ;
TEXT : ('a'..'z')+ ;
WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ -> skip ;
```

Would it be possible to generate all possible drinkSentences from this? I understand that e.g. the TEXT has a huge amount of possible combinations but for example's sake let's say that can only contain about 4 letters.

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes.  Is there something out there ready-made that will do it for you?  Probably not.  BTW: there are 456,976 different ways to form a "word" out of four letters...

Comment: Your grammar already contains all the productions. Do you mean 'sentences'?

Comment: @EJP yeah, I meant sentences. Wasn't clear in my wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible with any built-in ANTLR  functionality.

Comment: Bart, the question is not about doing that with built-in functionality

Comment: That wasn't 100% clear to me from the original question. I've seen questions before where people were under the impression ANTLR could provide similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My thought behind this was to skim through the sentences and look for any weird looking ones that would match not my expectation of what my grammar should accept. I looked though the docs and did a little research but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly doable, but you have to write a tool which does the job. To my knowledge there's no existing tool for this. A possible approach would be to walk the generated ATN and construct possible input from that.

However, I wonder for what you need such a generator. Is it that you want to create test input for your parser? If so you should think about this idea again. Your parser will always successfully parse correct input according to the grammar it was created for (assuming that there is no ANTLR4 bug here). How can you then test your always correctly working parser with your always correct input?

Comment: I wanted to look though the generated sentences and improve my grammar in case I find anything that doesn't match my expectations. Agree with your second point, though.

Comment: OK why not? I'm looking for use cases of such a generator for my vscode extension for ANTLR.